# why I get SIGUSR1 signal when I run my app in my device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

It was OK when it run in Simulator.
But when I run it in my ipad, i get this signal - "SIGUSR1"
I debug this program and I am sure it has run out of the viewDidLoad method in UIView Class.
Does someone know some common reason cause this problem?

Comment: That's strange. This is a POSIX user signal. Are you using any libraries that might use POSIX signals. [SIGUSR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGUSR1_and_SIGUSR2)

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was because of Backgrounder - so i uninstalled it, on a jailbroken i4

hope it helps somebody